# ASP.NET Core equivalent for ASP.NET MVC BeginExecuteCore

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am migrating from ASP.NET MVC to ASP.NET Core and the later does not have a [BeginExecuteCore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.controller.beginexecutecore?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) method in Controller.

Do you know a method in ASP.NET Core Controller that I could use to set Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture before the Request Action is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some litle code diving inside of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc package, I found that the class Controller has a couple of methods that help to control the execution of every Request Action.

This are OnActionExecuted and OnActionExecuting. Which run after and before the action execution respectively.

In my case, OnActionExecuting did the trick.